# Как вы проверяете кроссбраузерность ?

Tags: вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте я только учусь верстке возник вопрос как проверять верстку к разным браузерам нашел в инете варианты:
IE Tester   -Не понравился какой-то он весь глючной. 
multiple IE -Почитал про него одни минусы…
Вопрос к людям которые сейчас занимаются версткой.
Как проверяете верстку именно вы?

Comment: Установлены все основные браузеры. И поочерёдно проверяю как смотрится страничка во всех браузерах. Или вы имеете чтото другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарно: смотрю во всех браузерах)) при том, что Ыксплорер именно 8-ой смотрю

Comment: У меня установлен 9 IE как мне проверить под 7 и 8 ?

Comment: я думаю и 8 хватит

Comment: в отладчике можно выбрать режим совместимости(режим обозревателя ещё может вроде называться), отладчик вызывается клавишей F12, хотя всё равно  именно сам 8й установить будет лучше

Comment: Нашел и разобрался с этим режимом совместимости большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Люди! Если хотите кроссбраузерности ваших стилей, и не морочить себе голову по подгонке под разные браузеры, то выход есть!
Написав только CSS-код по стандартам W3C, представьте себе, можно получить кроссбраузерность. Для этого учите [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) и [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). Там предоставляются огромнейшие удобства для верстки и быстрого изменения всего-всего. И подчеркну, достаточно написать ТОЛЬКО ПО СТАНДАРТАМ W3C. Программа сама сгенерирует кроссбраузерный CSS.
На Compass написаны стили для ExtJs 4 и для многих других распространенных JS фреймфорков.

Comment: ага, только разработчики браузеров этот W3C почемуто понимают по разному.

Comment: и не призывайте людей учить костыли!

Comment: И чем же это "костыли"? Просветите. Вдруг мне захочется перестать это использовать.

Comment: И вообще как компас влияет на кроссбраузерность, не говоря уже о том, что должен быть установлен Руби?

Comment: Он генерирует кроссбраузерный стиль.

Comment: за: удобно и быстро в разработке, против: медленно и накладно.

"и для многих других" - например?

Comment: >> "и для многих других" - например?

На сайте Compass показаны ссылки. Но я не понимаю, почему медленно?!! Программа сгенерирует CSS-код в один сжатый файл, и этот файл укажете на странице в качестве файла стилей. Вот и вопрос: где медленный?

Comment: Т.к. ты написал "На Compass написаны стили для ExtJs 4" 

я решил что эта технология как-то используется динамически и тогда это работало бы медленно по определению. 

Статическое использование, как я понимаю, выгодно как не крути. Жаль что я не знал этого фреймворка когда был верстальщиком =)

Answer (score 1):

http://browsershots.org/ - полная проверка сайта. Вписываете сайт, ждёте пока приготовляться скрины и радуетесь.

Answer (score 0):

[IE tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) для IE подобных убожеств, для остального - конкретно смотрю в старых версиях того или иного браузера. Благо там незабываемых "приятных" впечатлений намного меньше

---

Пересел на расширение google chrome - [IE tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd)

Answer (score 0):

Нимогу не вмешаться. Проблема коректного отображения верстки различными браузерами есть, что-бы ни говорили. Восприятие стилей браузерами действительно разное. И мне приходится тестить страницы, именно просмотром их разными браузерами.